# How can I grab bunch of scss files and make one css file for all application

Tags: css, webpack, sass, gulp

I've got webpack.config and don't know what module I need to place in it, cause I found modules, whitch only minimises css or scss files, but not collecting them.

So I have 8-9 scss files, and need one css file, which collects all code from them

```html
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        home: './src/main/js/home/home.js',
        products: './src/main/js/products/products.js',
        product: './src/main/js/product/product.js',
        profile: './src/main/js/profile/profile.js',
        topics: './src/main/js/topics/topics.js',
        topic: './src/main/js/topic/topic.js',

    },
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/[name].bundle.js'

    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

What  module I Should install, and where I need to put code in webpack.config. Please help, I've never worked with webpack!

```html
var path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        home: './src/main/js/home/home.js',
        products: './src/main/js/products/products.js',
        product: './src/main/js/product/product.js',
        profile: './src/main/js/profile/profile.js',
        topics: './src/main/js/topics/topics.js',
        topic: './src/main/js/topic/topic.js',
        _article: './src/main/resources/static/sass/_article.scss',
        _catalog: './src/main/resources/static/sass/_catalog.scss',
        _home: './src/main/resources/static/sass/_home.scss',
        _header: './src/main/resources/static/sass/_header.scss',
        _footer: './src/main/resources/static/sass/_footer.scss',

    },
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/[name].bundle.js'

    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: [ /\.scss$/, path.join(__dirname, '.')],
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                })[{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
    ]
};
```

That'smy webpack.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webpack works different than gulp. Gulp is a task runner, which can work with `globs` and file patterns. Webpack is a bundler, which analyses the dependency tree given your entry points to be able to create your bundles.

In order to work with webpack, and bundle all scss files, they would need to be imported somewhere from your entry point. That is the only way that webpack will know these files exist.

Edit: Correct config.

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        home: './src/main/js/home/home.js',
        products: './src/main/js/products/products.js',
        product: './src/main/js/product/product.js',
        profile: './src/main/js/profile/profile.js',
        topics: './src/main/js/topics/topics.js',
        topic: './src/main/js/topic/topic.js',
        _article: './src/main/resources/static/sass/_article.scss',
        _catalog: './src/main/resources/static/sass/_catalog.scss',
        _home: './src/main/resources/static/sass/_home.scss',
        _header: './src/main/resources/static/sass/_header.scss',
        _footer: './src/main/resources/static/sass/_footer.scss',

    },
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Comment: so I need to import all my scss files like js files?

Comment: imported, what am I need to do then? Add some plugin?

Comment: add css-loader, sass-loader. If you want to extract them to css files add mini-css-extract-plugin

Comment: installed, it's ok, but I've got an error while spring-boot:run

Comment: placed my webpack.config, am I did something wrong?

Comment: everything... the configuration is totally incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185547/discussion-between-pawmaw-and-playma256).